# Vercel - ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined (nextjs)

Tags: vercel

My code works in local but when I deploy on Vercel, I got this error:

`ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined`

and:
`Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1`

This is part of the code in NavBar.jsx

```
const [isDarkTheme, toggleTheme] = useToggler(() => {
    if (typeof window !== undefined) {
     return localStorage.getItem("theme-color") === "dark";
    }
  });


  useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.className = isDarkTheme ? "dark" : "";
    localStorage.setItem("theme-color", isDarkTheme ? "dark" : "light");
  }, [isDarkTheme]);
```

Any suggestions?

My code on Git: https://github.com/thusmiley/dictionary.git